# Implicit Intent not showing Gallery in Android Lollipop

Tags: android, android-intent, mobile

Developing a social Application, For profile pic  I want to give user two options  either he would select the image from Gallery or Take photo , for this purpose I am using Implicit Intent .

Code :

> ```
>                    Intent intent = new Intent (Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
>                 intent.addCategory (Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
>                 intent.setType ("image/jpeg");
>
>                 Intent takePhotoIntent = new Intent (MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
>
>                 String pickTitle = "Select or take a new Picture"; // Or get from strings.xml
>                 Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser (intent, pickTitle);
>                 chooserIntent.putExtra
>                         (
>                                 Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS,
>                                 new Intent[]{takePhotoIntent}
>                         );
>
>                 startActivityForResult (chooserIntent, GALLERY_KITKAT_INTENT_CALLED);
>             }
> ```

But Intent is showing Document + Camera only

[image]

NO Gallery

What is wrong  with this intent why its not showing Gallery ?

testing Deveice : Android Lollipop

Comment: can u use set type as intent.setType("*/*"); .. this may help

Comment: @ Riten how  can this help,I think  it may not

Comment: can you please try with "image/*"? also what do you get open you select the icon all documents or just images?

Comment: @petrumo just images

Comment: @AndroidMan did you ever figure out why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with what is shown.

You have two options `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` and `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` which you can choose by `Documents or Camera`.

If you choose `Documents` you will get the normal chooser for `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`.

After that you can choose 'the gallery'.

Comment: @ greenapp I want to show gallery at the place of Document